# how to make that Console.ReadLine doesnt print the line when entered but prints the line a line break after the print?

Tags: c#

so if you dont understand, its like playing minecraft and sending something in chat it says

```
<player> hello
|
```

my C# code adds a hello before it:

```
hello
<player> hello
|
```

the pipe symbl resembles the text that blinks that disapper and appear.

here is my code:

```
namespace GSoft
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(name + " Has Joined The World of chats!");
            Console.Write("Join(type join) or create a server(type create): ");
            String ip = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ip == "join") {
                Console.Write("Join a group/server: ");
                String serverip = Console.ReadLine();
                if (serverip == serveripm) { }
            }
            else if (ip == "create")
            {
                Console.Write("Create a group/server: ");
                priString serveripm = Console.ReadLine();
            chat:
                Console.WriteLine("<" + name + "> " + Console.ReadLine());
                goto chat;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your example and your code do not match.  No where in your code is the word hello, or player 1.  Provide an example that uses your code for better assistance.

Comment: that is just an example not the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your issue here isn't that your code is outputting a duplicate of your text, but rather that it's showing what you type, which is expected behavior.
There's a couple ways to counteract this, depending on your situation.
The easiest way is to overwrite the text before you write the next line:

```cs
namespace GSoft
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(name + " Has Joined The World of chats!");
            Console.Write("Join(type join) or create a server(type create): ");
            String ip = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ip == "join") {
                Console.Write("Join a group/server: ");
                String serverip = Console.ReadLine();
                if (serverip == serveripm) { }
            }
            else if (ip == "create")
            {
                Console.Write("Create a group/server: ");
                priString serveripm = Console.ReadLine();
                string message;
            chat:
                message = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.CursorTop--;
                // Normally you'd write over the message with blank characters, but since you're just prepending the name, it will already overwrite the entire text.
                // Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth) + '\r');
                Console.WriteLine("<" + name + "> " + message);
                goto chat;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, overwriting it may not be suitable if you're writing to the console at the same time as reading from it. In a case like this, you'd need to read individual keys, and maintain your own buffer. Here's a very basic example:

```cs
Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
String name = Console.ReadLine();
string message = "";
chat:
    ConsoleKey key;
    while((key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            message = message[..^1];
        else
            message += (char)key;
    }
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth) + '\r');
    Console.WriteLine("<" + name + "> " + message);
    goto chat;
```